# Google Search Console "linked from" obsolete sitemap

Tags: sitemap, google-search-console

Why does Google Search Console show "linked from" links that are from sitemap entries that are no longer part of the sitemap? I have pages from 10 years ago that show up that haven't been part of my sitemap for a decade, but they still show "linked from" the sitemap.

Comment: Where does it show that? Google shouldn't be caching sitemaps... but rather reading them as you go.

Comment: When I look at the "Linked From" list, it gives the sitemap URL. But the 404 page isn't in the sitemap.